# Does Qt support iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, qt, qt5

I want to know whether it is possible to develop iPhone applications using Qt Framework.
Please suggest me some references if aforementioned is possible.

Comment: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/04/08/qt-5-1-alpha-available/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep an eye out for Qt 5.2.

Here is the current status on it (like @thelaws said):

https://www.qt.io/blog/2013/04/08/qt-5-1-alpha-available

There have been some Labs available through Qt Lighthouse for iOS support.

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7271

Hope that helps.

Comment: ,, still ,i m not getting point, if it support ios ,then is there some video tutorial available??

Comment: It's still in alpha, I guess they will have proper docs for the final release version.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to wait until the Qt 5.2 release have a look at [V-Play](http://v-play.net/) (v-play.net).  It's a cross platform game engine based on Qt/QML. (Here are also some docs about it: [API reference](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-group.html))

Alex

Answer (score 0):

With Qt.5.1.1 out now, we can update this as follows: Assuming you have Xcode installed, and already know about iPhone development, you might go here next:

[Qt 5.1.1 - Known Issues for IOS](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_iOS_known_issues/)

[Qt 5.1.1 - IOS Support](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/ios-support.html/)

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled Qt 5.2 beta 1 for iOS and wrote down detailed compilation instructions. Works fine.

See my answer in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19605007/2366874).