# Creating Qt 5.1 apps for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, qt, qt5

The new Qt 5.1 has (partial) support for iOS as mentioned in the [release announcement](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/07/03/qt-5-1-released/), but how do I actually build and deploy a Qt project to a iOS device? Or in other words, how do I end up with a iOS XCode project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This shows how to compile qt5 for the iOS simulator.

Based on [qt build instructions for iOS](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/ios-support.html).

If you want to build for an iOS device, you have to check out the qt5 sources a second time to a second directory and use the alternate configure command as shown below.

This uses qt 5.2 beta 1. Check for newer versions with `git tag`.

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git qt5-ios-simulator.git
cd qt5-ios-simulator.git
git tag
git reset --hard v5.2.0-beta1
```

Initialize qt but do not use webkit because it takes too long to compile

```
perl init-repository --no-webkit
```

Configure qt to use open source version with simulator, skipping examples and test

```
./configure -xplatform macx-ios-clang -developer-build -opensource -release -nomake examples -nomake tests -sdk iphonesimulator
```

Alternatively, use this configure command in a separate git checkout to build for iOS devices

```
./configure -xplatform macx-ios-clang -developer-build -opensource -release -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

Run make. Uses 4 jobs in parallel for faster compilation.

```
make -j 4
cd ..
```

Done.

You may test if everything works by building an example project

```
git clone https://github.com/msorvig/qt-ios-demo.git
cd qt-ios-demo
../qt5-ios-simulator.git/qtbase/bin/qmake 
open qt-ios-demo.xcodeproj
```

Comment: I tried solution provided by "Infinite Loop" but it keeps saying: ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/opt/local/lib/libz.dylib' for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) I'm using XCode5 on OS X Mavericks & IOS Simulator 7. Has anybody undergone/solved this issue?

Comment: Qt 5.2 has full support for iOS and Qt Creator 3 will have a plugin to integrate with MacOSX tool chain. It should be out Dec 10th 2013. The mobile edition has a commercial subscription licence for iOS development. I'm very interested in the idea of iOS + Android dev with QML, very cool :)

Comment: when I try to run make it says: "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.". Do you know how this could be resolved?

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried it myself yet but I would guess have to install XCode and Qt Creator on your OSX. As I know the Qt guys its probably like the Android version. Just try to install the Qt SDK with the online installer and select the iOS version. The rest should be possible in QtCreator. I would be interested to know if it worked.

Comment: There is no iOS version option in the online or offline installers :( And I'm also unable to find any iOS device option in Qt Creator. Android is installed automatically and is easily found in the Qt Creator.

Comment: You are right I have tried it now on OSX myself. Seems like one has to compile Qt for iOS manually like mentioned here: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/03/05/qt-for-ios-preview/

Comment: I just found out that there are pre-built packages available from a third party vendor at: http://mediator-software.com/
Maybe they can help you.

Comment: Qt 5.2 alpha has just been released, with better support for iOS development. You still need to partially build Qt, here are the instructions: [Qt 5.2 alpha iOS support](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/ios-support.html). You can read the full announcement in [Qt blog here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/09/30/qt-5-2-alpha-available/).